# disable all keyup/keydown/keypressed events present on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having plenty of key events here on my page.Is there any way to disable all the keyup/keydown/keypressed events present on page rather than disabling each event separately.
i am looking for solution using javascript/jquery.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You *could* do it this way, though I expect it might be horrendously slow on larger pages:

```
$('*').off('keyup keydown keypress');
```

That's going to select every single element on the page, then remove any `keyup`, `keydown`, and `keypress` events that are bound to them.

If you want to prevent the user from using the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to navigate to the previous page, you could try the following code:

```
var inputTags = ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'];

$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 8 && $.inArray(e.target.tagName, inputTags) === -1)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

That should restrict the use of the backspace key, except in instances where the focus is an input element where you can enter text (so an `<input type="text">` or a `<textarea>`).

Take a look at this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FqFmF/1/).

Comment: will this prevent page to redirect to previous page on press of backspace?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar No, that's a built-in browser function, not an event handler that's added to the page using jQuery. You might be able to *add* an event handler to prevent that if that's your intended goal, I'd have to check.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I've edited my answer to include some information on how you'd go about preventing using the backspace key to navigate through previous history items.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).find('*').off('keyup keydown keypressed');
```

and you should put this into the `$(document).ready()` block, after all the loaded JS on page (before `</body>` tag, for example).

Comment: will this prevent page to redirect to previous page on press of backspace?

Comment: I'm not sure if `backspace` keypress is followed by html `document` or browser's `window`. But I think it should be followed by the browser's `window`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use preventDefault() function to solve it

Comment: No, you can't.  That prevents the default action AFTER the events have already run.  If you want to stop the event handlers themselves from running, you either need to detach them OR have a higher-priority event (a feature JavaScript doesn't support but ActionScript 3 has supported for a decade) and then call stopImmediatePropagation, which will prevent other handlers attached to the node from running as well as handler attached to parent nodes.  But there's no way to set event priority in JavaScript, so essentially there's still no way to disable keyboard events in 2017 in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

$('*').unbind('keyup keydown keypress')

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this combination:

Turn on keypress event

```js
$(document).keypress(function(){
// Code
});
```

and for turning off this event I have used:

```js
$(document).off('keypress');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(elem).off('keypress.jstree')`

I recently struggled with this as well since I was adding editing features to tree nodes.  By looking at the source, I noticed there's an event `keypress.jstree` being bound with a timeout of 500ms.

Simply adding the above `off` binding after initializing the tree solved all my issues at once!  This works both for static tree structures as well as tree's loaded with ajax data.  The version I'm currently using is 3.3.5

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This code deletes the last key pressed in TextBox2, by using  substr.

```
 `$("#TextBox2").val($("#TextBox2").val().substr(0, ($("#TextBox2").val().length-1)));`
  //removes last letter pressed.
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant w.r.t. OP's question. Recommending deletion.